# Is there a way to export a BigQuery table's schema as JSON?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

A BigQuery [table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables) has schema which can be viewed in the web UI, [updated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#updateschema), or used to [load data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) with the `bq` tool as a JSON file. However, I can't find a way to dump this schema from an existing table to a JSON file (preferably from the command-line). Is that possible?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

> a way to dump schema from an existing table to a JSON file (preferably from the command-line). Is that possible?

try below

```
bq show bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia
```

You can use –format flag to prettify output

--format: none|json|prettyjson|csv|sparse|pretty:

Format for command output. Options include:

```
none:       ...
pretty:     formatted table output  
sparse:     simpler table output  
prettyjson: easy-to-read JSON format  
json:       maximally compact JSON  
csv:        csv format with header
```

The first three are intended to be human-readable, and the latter three are
for passing to another program. If no format is selected, one will be chosen
based on the command run.

Realized I provided partial answer :o)

Below does what PO wanted

```
bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia | jq '.schema.fields'
```

Comment: Thank you. I kept looking for other keywords like "export" and "dump", as well as the word "schema", and none of the docs for "show" had that.

Comment: i would recommend to explore bq command directly in Google Cloud SDK Shell. Just start with bq --help and ... :o)

Comment: For posterity, this command does what I wanted:

`bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia | jq '.schema.fields'`

Comment: is there any way forward the output into a text file? my schema definitions are to large for the terminal

Comment: just add   "> yourfile.json" at the end without quotation marks

Comment: Here is a link to download jq, if its not already on your system: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: With windows I found that the quotation mark `"` is needed instead of apostrophe `'`, so as follows: `bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia | jq ".schema.fields" `

Comment: why I am getting this error when using --format as csv or pretty "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5"

Comment: @vikrantrana The `jq` command parses json. If you want another format, you have to omit that part.

Comment: It's been a while, but in order for the `bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia | jq '.schema.fields'` to function, one needs to also include the flag `--apilog=stderr` lest the final `jq` command will encounter a parsing error **jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6**

Answer (score 124):

You can add the flag `--schema`[1] in order to avoid table data information.

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] > [SCHEMA_FILE]

bq show --schema --format=prettyjson myprojectid:mydataset.mytable > /tmp/myschema.json
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

Comment: Excellent! It looks like that was added a few months after I asked this question, in Cloud SDK version 165. Much better than relying on `jq`.

Answer (score 37):

1. select table on the bq UI.
2. select columns you would want to export schema for.
3. use the copy menu to copy schema as JSON.

[image: table schema]

Answer (score 12):

**Answer update**

Since October 2020,
you can also run a SQL query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` which is kind of an introspective functionality.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM <YOUR_DATASET>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

and nest the data using an aggregation function such as

```sql
SELECT table_name, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column_name, data_type)) as columns
FROM <YOUR_DATASET>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY table_name
```

The are also interesting metadata in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` if you also need the source code from your views.

Then hit save results / JSON from the BigQuery interface, or wrap it into the `bq query` command line in your case.

Source: [BigQuery release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#October_19_2020)

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted solution for 2021

Comment: This was perfect - would just add SELECT ddl column specifically, and a WHERE clause with the desired table_name

Answer (score 4):

You can use REST API call to get BigQuery table schema as JSON. Documentation link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get

```
curl 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project-name/datasets/dataset-name/tables/table-name' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --compressed
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I was looking for the API version. Is there a way to do this without an HTTP call?  Is a function like this just what all more 'native' looking functions of the API look like under the hood?  (I mean that normal functions are not HTTP calls). I just don't want it to be slow  and "calls" seems slow.

Comment: When I usually load data etc I don't need to think of Authentication for instance. @Soumendra Mishra

Answer (score 2):

As of 15th May 2022, this worked:

1. In google cloud, Go to cloud shell
2. Select the project from drop down (left) of cloud shell
3. Use below command
   bq show --schema --format=prettyjson .

Answer (score 1):

The following bash script & sql always helped me solve the problem to extract all tables schema to JSON file from a dataset:

```
#!/bin/bash
#gen-default-schema.sh
input=$1
source_type=$2
result=tables_${source_type}.result

bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false --flagfile=$input | awk '{if(NR>1)print}' > $result

while IFS= read -r line
do
    tbl_name=`echo "$line" | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
    schema_file=`echo "$tbl_name" | cut -d'_' -f2-`.schema
    echo $schema_file
    bq show --schema --format=prettyjson $line > ./temp/${source_type}/${schema_file}
    echo "done"
done < "$result"
```

Input file `example.sql` ($1)

```
SELECT
  table_catalog || ":" || table_schema || "." || table_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name
  FROM
    `project-id`.<dataset_id>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  ORDER BY
    table_name ASC )
```

To run:

```
$bash gen-default-schema.sh example.sql example
```

This will place all the JSON schema under `./temp` folder

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do this from google `cloud-console` then a short `SQL` query can achieve this.

It'll give you all the info from schema and you can change the `STRUCT( ... )` with https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-column-field-paths#schema as you wish.

Alternatively use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.<something>` with other views to get different meta info to JSON.

As @Michel Hua said in their answer, select `Query results -> JSON` in bigquery to get JSON after running the SQL query

```
SELECT table_name, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column_name, data_type, description)) as columns
FROM `your-project-id`.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name' 
GROUP BY table_name
```