# BigQuery Terraform Create Table If Not Exists

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am looking to create some Terraform modules to manage datasets & tables within BigQuery.

I am looking for an equivalent of the DDL "[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_table_only_if_the_table_doesnt_exist)" command.   I want to be able to continue to build upon this codebase over time, and once I start using these tables, I don't want them to get dropped & recreated each time I run the Terraform.

I have tried both the "[terraform-google-modules/bigquery](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-bigquery#variable-tables-detailed-description)" module as well as the stand alone "[bigquery_table_create](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/bigquery/bigquery_create_table/main.tf)" resource [as referenced in the GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#create_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition).

If I set the `deletion_protection` [argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table#deletion_protection) to `true`, this keeps the resource from being destroyed, but throws an error when I run the `terraform apply`

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "advisor-population" {
  table_id           = "advisor_population"
  dataset_id = "advisors"
  schema             =  file("${path.module}/advisor_population.json")
  expiration_time = null
  #only create the table if it doesn't already exist
  deletion_protection = true
  clustering      = []
  labels          = {
    env     = var.environment
    project = "lava"
  }
}
```

The object is still scheduled to be replaced when I run `terraform plan`.   **Edit**:  note that this behavior is the case even if not additions or changes to the scheme or any other table attributes, which seems inconsistent with most terraform resource behavior.

```
  # module.wisc-tl-data-lake-advisors.google_bigquery_table.advisor-population must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "advisor-population" {
      ~ creation_time       = 1699629882718 -> (known after apply)
      ~ etag                = "2rxbC0hgF0zvUQoVLgyx8A==" -> (known after apply)
      ~ expiration_time     = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                  = "projects/doit-at-lace-dev-d96a/datasets/advisors/tables/advisor_population" -> (known after apply)
      ~ last_modified_time  = 1699629882778 -> (known after apply)
      ~ location            = "US" -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_bytes           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_long_term_bytes = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_rows            = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ project             = "doit-at-lace-dev-d96a" -> (known after apply)
      ~ schema              = jsonencode(
          ~ [
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "advisor_pvi"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "advisor_netid"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "population"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
            ] # forces replacement
        )
      ~ self_link           = "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/doit-at-lace-dev-d96a/datasets/advisors/tables/advisor_population" -> (known after apply)
      ~ type                = "TABLE" -> (known after apply)
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

And then just errors out when I run `apply`.  The good news is it doesn't get deleted, but I obviously don't want to develop a codebase where I have a bunch of errors and need to remember which ones I 'expect' to see.

```
  # module.wisc-tl-data-lake-advisors.google_bigquery_table.advisor-population must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "advisor-population" {
      ~ creation_time       = 1699629882718 -> (known after apply)
      ~ etag                = "2rxbC0hgF0zvUQoVLgyx8A==" -> (known after apply)
      ~ expiration_time     = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                  = "projects/doit-at-lace-dev-d96a/datasets/advisors/tables/advisor_population" -> (known after apply)
      ~ last_modified_time  = 1699629882778 -> (known after apply)
      ~ location            = "US" -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_bytes           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_long_term_bytes = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ num_rows            = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ project             = "doit-at-lace-dev-d96a" -> (known after apply)
      ~ schema              = jsonencode(
          ~ [
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "advisor_pvi"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "advisor_netid"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
              ~ {
                  + fields      = []
                    name        = "population"
                    # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
                },
            ] # forces replacement
        )
      ~ self_link           = "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/doit-at-lace-dev-d96a/datasets/advisors/tables/advisor_population" -> (known after apply)
      ~ type                = "TABLE" -> (known after apply)
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Comment: If you modify a resource such that the GCP API and its associated provider determine that it must be re-created, then preventing its deletion would block the updates.

Comment: That's also a good call out - I'm assuming that would apply if I added a new column to the schema, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for those who may come across this question.

It turns out that the reason terraform was dropping and recreating the table every time I ran my code is because I [generated my schema JSON from the GCP console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195143/is-there-a-way-to-export-a-bigquery-tables-schema-as-json) rather than via the CLI.

Because it didn't exactly match the JSON generated by the API, it thought the object had changed every single time.   The important bit is listed as a ["note"](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table#schema) in the Terraform docs:

[image: Because this field expects a JSON string, any changes to the string will create a diff, even if the JSON itself hasn't changed. If the API returns a different value for the same schema, e.g. it switched the order of values or replaced STRUCT field type with RECORD field type, we currently cannot suppress the recurring diff this causes. As a workaround, we recommend using the schema as returned by the API.]

If you generate the JSON schema from the API, all is right with the world and it doesn't attempt to destroy and recreate the table every time

`bq show --schema <<project name>>:<<dataset name>>.<<table name>>`